# What is it called when someone denies a crime despite not having been accused?

Tags: phrases, expressions, legalese

I heard the phrase a while ago, it was two words I believe. The instance was a woman was approached by police and before they said anything to her she said "I wasn't soliciting" denying a crime she had not been accused of, the officer replied by telling her what she had done, using the phrase I am looking for.

Note, this was on tv, I'm not wandering places where people yell "I'm not soliciting"

Comment: Sounds similar to *apophasis*.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis

Comment: like a "guilty conscience"?

Comment: well, I would describe it as a Preemptive denial ,  but are you looking for a legal term, I'm not so sure yet

Comment: I'd like to know what the TV show was, since it's pertinent information to the question. Knowing it was on TV, I'd guess something like: "You jumped the gun." That phrase means to have a mistaken start in a race or competition that is started by firing off a blank round, meaning the person went before that round got fired (and before the race actually started).

Comment: 'Your words, not mine' point out the possibly self-accusatory nature of this.

Comment: "Note, this was on tv, I'm not wandering places where people yell 'I'm not soliciting'". I think it's funny that this statement is an example of your question.

Comment: You realise that adding 'Note, this was on tv, I'm not wandering places where people yell "I'm not soliciting" ' is doing almost exactly the same (with dodgy activity rather than crime)?

Answer (score 5):

There is a line from Hamlet by Hamlet by William Shakespeare that people use in these cases:

> The lady doth protest too much, methinks.

As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lady_doth_protest_too_much,_methinks):

> The line is typically quoted (or misquoted, as in "methinks the lady doth protest too much") to suggest that someone who is strongly denying something is hiding the truth,[2] or to imply doubt in a person's sincerity.[4] The phrase can be used this way even when the subject is male.[3]

You can look up the references at Wikipedia.

That expression would only apply if the lady in question was in fact guilty of the crime she was denying.

Answer (score 3):

The common human reaction of denying involvement even in the absence of a formal accusation is called the "exculpatory no." In the US, lying to a federal officer is a crime. One defense to this charge prior to 1998 is the exculpatory no. In that year the Supreme Court abolished the defense. See Brogan v. U.S., 522 U.S. 398 (1998). So, the officer could say, "that's an exculpatory no, I didn't even ask you what you were doing here."

Comment: But in the USA the more common, and more likely, response by someone accused of a crime would be to plead his right to refuse to answer where to answer might tend to incriminate him: a right granted by the 5th Amendment to the Constitution, and popularly known as _taking the 5th_.

Comment: Taking the Fifth, or saying, "I want a lawyer," or even just repeating the word "lawyer" is not a denial. The issue isn't what do people say while under interrogation, the question was "What is it called when someone denies a crime despite not having been accused?" There is a certain amount of ambiguity because a policeman saying, "You killed Joe" is not a formal accusation--policeman do not file formal charges, the State attorney (or federally, a grand jury does.) When the courts analyzed the interaction, they called it an "exculpatory no." See above.

Comment: The suggestion that taking the 5th is not a denial is absolutely correct: everyone knows perfectly well it's an admission of guilt. Ordinary people, i.e. the sort of people who sit on juries, are rarely impressed by the legalistic hair-splitting that _pretends_ it is not an admission. This forum is not a law forum, but a language forum, and in ordinary usage _taking the 5th_ is an expression that is commonly used to mean: _the accused is denying the charge (of which he must be guilty, because only guilty people have something to hide)_. Whatever the legal position, that's the common meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the phrase you're looking for is, "unprovoked denial." I was trying to remember it too so I did a quick search and came across your question. When I found it in my notes, I came back to your post to let you know.

Comment: Another option that could fit is, "preemptive denial," but the one I had heard and wanted to remember was, "unprovoked denial."  (I have to give credit to 2 people very dear to me who came up with preemptive denial when I had asked for their help. I was amazed that they both responded with exactly the same phrase!)

Comment: There’s generally no need to comment on your own post; especially if it’s an *unprovoked comment* :) .    (If somebody else comments, it is often appropriate to reply with a comment.)   For afterthoughts, you should just [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might call it **deflecting blame**, or **deflecting**. She might be **sidestepping** an investigation or trying to "**ward off**" the inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom:  **don't look at me**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+Look+at+Me)

> 1. An exclamation of innocence from a general accusation or implication of wrongdoing, with the emphasis placed on "me."

As in:

> Jane: "All right, which one of you kids broke the vase in the living
>   room?" Tom: "Don't look at me! I've been playing outside all day!"

Comment: But (and the example is of this form) this is [almost?] always in response to a general verbal accusation. The police in the OP example might have merely been looking for information. '[B]efore they said anything to her she said ...'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didnt mean someone who pleads "no contest" or nolo contendre? In NY it is called an Alford plea.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. What you've written here would have been better suited to being a comment, you will be able to leave those on other's posts as soon as you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Pleading "no contest" is a statement that you don't intend to fight the charges against you. It's not the same as denying accusations before they are made.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strong case of **paralipsis**.

@RaceYouAnytime commented [a strong link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis) that references paralipsis.

Answer (score -1):

How about a one word answer:  ***incriminate***

to incriminate:  *to involve in an accusation; cause to be or appear to be guilty; implicate:*

For example:
He feared incriminating himself if he answered.

[Reference](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incriminate)

I bet the cop yelled, "You've incriminated yourself, lady!"

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so... You understand that I'm making this suggestion because it was something you *saw on tv.*

In an episode of the American tv series *Columbo*, a police series, which I saw as a repeat last week, the woman said something like that to star Peter Falk, who plays the eponymous detective. And he asked her: *Are you taking the Fifth, mam?*

In the United States, there is a common expression, *to take the Fifth*, derived from the 5th Amendment to the American Constitution, which entitles a person accused of a crime to refuse to answer the accusation if the answer would tend to incriminate him.

So if the wife accuses me of watching *Columbo*, when I ought to have been out walking the dog, I might **take the Fifth**, rather than incriminate myself by an admission.

(Columbo has a dog himself, and it appears in a lot of the 1990's episodes. My dog enjoys the show, because he thinks the *dog* is its star! At least, that's what I ended up telling my wife...)

Comment: That isn't what the question asked though. In the OP's example the woman didn't try to remain silent, she spoke up to deny a specific charge that had not been made.

Comment: Hey, I went thru that whole rigmarole just to get in my best joke, about the dog, and this is how you treat me???     :-)

Comment: Well I didn't vote you down, if that's what you mean. I stand by my comment, but I did like your joke.

Answer (score -1):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org

**self-incrimination** meaning: 1. saying or doing something that shows that you are guilty of a crime:

"That's self-incrimination," said the officer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-incrimination

Self-incrimination can occur either directly or indirectly:

directly, by means of interrogation where information of a self-incriminatory nature is disclosed;

**or indirectly, when information of a self-incriminatory nature is disclosed voluntarily without pressure from another person.[2]**

Answer (score -1):

"Freudian slip" could also apply.

Sigmund Freud argued that personality is formed through conflicts among three fundamental structures of the human mind: the id, ego, and superego. He thought that one's true suppressed [sexual] feelings can show themselves, slip out in error, when one is under stress and unable to maintain the facade constructed to hide ones true feelings or beliefs. The woman, when confronted by the police officer was unable to maintain the falsehood that she was not, in fact, soliciting and, because she knew that she was, she verbalised the thought unconsciously - as Freud suggests, hence a Freudian Slip.

Comment: What does "Freudian slip" mean and why is it suitable here?

Comment: Sigmund Freud argued that personality is formed through conflicts among three fundamental structures of the human mind: the id, ego, and superego.  He thought that one's true suppressed [sexual] feelings can show themselves, slip out in error, when one is under stress and unable to maintain the facade constructed to hide ones true feelings or beliefs. The woman, when confronted by the police officer was unable to maintain the falsehood that she was not, in fact, soliciting and, because she knew that she was, she verbalised the thought unconsciously - as Freud suggests, hence a Freudian Slip.

Comment: You should include that level of detail when you create an answer. As it is you should edit it into your answer as comments can be deleted.